# ansible playbook : changes not getting reflected

Tags: ansible

I have written ansible-playbook to configure hostname on VyOS server.
Playbook is not giving any errors, But changes are not getting reflected on VyOS

Here is the playbook:

```
--- 
 - hosts : server1
   vars:
    inventory_hostname : vyos_host
   name : setting host name
      vyos_config
        lines
          - set system host-name {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

default host file i am using is :

/etc/ansible/project/hostfile

```
[server1]
192.168.1.82

[sever2]
192.168.1.88
```

Answer (score 0):

Your playbook missing `tasks` block, proper spacing and colons, it should be written like

```
--- 
 - hosts : server1
   vars:
     inventory_hostname : vyos_host
   tasks:
     - name : setting host name
       vyos_config:
         lines:
           - set system host-name {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Plese check [Intro to Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html) and [YAML syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html) in official documentation

Comment: why is it not giving any syntax error? It shows as Ok=1

Comment: Because you provided valid yaml, which can be represented as following JSON: `[
 {
  "hosts": "server1",
  "name": "setting host name vyos_config lines - set system host-name {{ inventory_hostname }}",
  "vars": {
   "inventory_hostname": "vyos_host"
  }
 }
]` 
Without specifying tasks or roles you told ansible to do nothing.